# Issues escaping special characters in batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, escaping, xmlstarlet

I am using xmlstarlet to edit an xml file. I am facing issues with these two commands specifically.

```
xml ed -P --update /ns2:ExportManifest/ExportManifestEntity[@path='home/user_name/11.05 CFD Developer commits.xanalyzer']/ExportManifestProperty/EntityMetaData/@name -v 11.05 CFD Developer commits.xanalyzer someFile.xml > someFileNew.xml & move /Y someFileNew.xml someFile.xml
```

This command doesn't do what it is supposed to. After I run the above coomand, I find the file empty. Is there anything I need to escape to make this command work?

Second one have the percentage sign. And I found that in the batch file I can escape it by using `%%`. But it doesn't seem to to be working fine and I find an empty file same as above.

```
xml ed -P --update /ns2:ExportManifest/ExportManifestEntity[@path='home/user_name/11.05.DEV CFD commits %%28feature %%26 bug%%29 by Program.xanalyzer']/ExportManifestProperty/EntityMetaData/@name -v 11.05.DEV CFD commits (feature & bug) by Program.xanalyzer someFile.xml > someFileNew.xml & move /Y someFileNew.xml someFile.xml
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See the `(feature & bug)` portion of your command line: the ampersand needs to be escaped like `^&`; in case this code is placed in between a pair of parentheses, you need to escape the `)` like `^)`...

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. Did you find anything in the first command?

Comment: I replaced (feature & bug) with ^(feature ^& bug^) but I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you try that with the doubled `%` signs you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't work.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is with the spaces. Xpath is not able to match anything which has spaces.

Comment: Are you talking about the part in between `''`? could you use `""` instead?

Comment: Yes. I tried " " too but then it says "Invalid expression".

Comment: Okay... so the last idea I have is to escape all problematic spaces by preceding a `^` symbol...

Comment: Finally I got it working man. I will post the answer. I didn't escape anything other than %. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

When executing the xmlstarlet commands in the the batch file , you have to be very careful with spaces in the attribute values. I had to use `""` to tell windows that everything is `String` here. But I had to use `''` too to make sure that the attribute value gets read and matched successfully. Here's the solution:

New value that will replace the old one should be in the double quotes too.

```
xml ed -P --update /ns2:ExportManifest/ExportManifestEntity[@path="'home/user_name/11.05 CFD Developer commits.xanalyzer'"]/ExportManifestProperty/EntityMetaData/@name -v "11.05 CFD Developer commits.xanalyzer" someFile.xml > someFileNew.xml & move /Y someFileNew.xml someFile.xml
```

I did the same thing for the second command:

```
xml ed -P --update /ns2:ExportManifest/ExportManifestEntity[@path="'home/user_name/11.05.DEV CFD commits %%28feature %%26 bug%%29 by Program.xanalyzer'"]/ExportManifestProperty/EntityMetaData/@name -v "11.05.DEV CFD commits (feature & bug) by Program.xanalyzer" someFile.xml > someFileNew.xml & move /Y someFileNew.xml someFile.xml
```

Comment: The `"` tells the Windows not to split the argument by whitespace, the `'` indicates a string literal to xmlstarlet. You can put the `"` around the whole argument (`--update "/ns2:ExportManifest..../@name" -v`)